# vim leaves a swapfile after crash with unknown owner

Tags: windows, vim, crash, swap

I am running Cygwin on windows. Several times now I've had a swap file left behind from vim after a crash, but it can't be recovered or deleted. "ls -l" shows this:

```
-rw-r-----  1 Unknown+User Unknown+Group  12288 Feb 26 15:27 .pl.pl.swp
```

I'm not allowed to be an admin on my box, so I can't delete it. I'm not the owner so I cant' delete it either - it has unknown ownership.

Any ideas on how I can delete it (without pulling in a machine admin each time)? Can I have vim put its swapfiles in some other folder so at least they won't clutter up my working dir?

Comment: The first troubleshooting step is for a machine admin to determine what the actual ownership of the file is. If it really isn't yours, there's something badly wrong with your machine (because that's not supposed to be possible) and determining the actual owner is likely to help diagnose the problem. (I assume you've tried rebooting, to confirm that it isn't just that some process has a lock on the file?)

Comment: What does windows `explorer` -> `properties` -> `security` say about the file?

Comment: It says, you do not have permission to view or edit this object's permission settings. I have a feeling that this might be normal for a vim swap file, but that it's normally not noticed, because most windows users would naturally be admins on their own machines. However my company doesn't allow that. If I could point my swap files to another folder with .vimrc settings, that would not solve but bypass the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off swap file creation altogether by adding

```
set noswapfile
```

in your `.vimrc` file.